# IPython Auto Scroll?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In IPython, if I run a cell, the browser scrolls to put the cell near the bottom of the page. If this happens when I plot a chart, then I can't see the chart and have to scroll down manually. How can I stop this happening?

Answer (score 1):

**I feel your frustration!**

This will probably depend on where you plotter functionality is within your ipython notebook, but one solution (especially if it is in the last cell) is to create many blank cells below your plotter cell (say 10 to 20) then use Ctrl + Enter to run the plotter cell. This may need some playing around with but I have gotten this to work for me!

*(I think the idea of Ctrl + Enter is to keep the cell where it is)*